# How to insert in parent and child tables in Talend?

Tags: talend

I have 2 tables: `student` and `studentmarks`. I want to insert first in `student` and then insert in `studentmarks` in Talend. How can I achieve this task?

Comment: Write a query to insert first table, and check the success status. Once it is success then insert in another table.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-database-tutorial.html)? Especially interesting for you up until the end of the part **Creating Our Data**.

Comment: Would this be raw sql or insert using application?